# Is there a way to connect Google Colab ipynb file with a Node js backend?

Tags: node.js, google-colaboratory

I have a deep learning based model which is implemented in a Google Colab ipynb file, and I want to make a web application from it using MERN stack. In the web application, when user requests, deep learning model in Google Colab should be run and the output of the model should be shown to the user...I was wondering whether there is any way to connect the code at Google Colab with the backend. Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @emkarachchi There is no way to connect Colab directly, We have to obtain the python code and using Flask we can connect our model and backend.

Comment: You need to export your model using a library like Pickle and invoke that model file in your node.js backend